# Axios GET Request to MySql Produces Error 404

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to connect my CRUD app to MySQL (react, nodeJS, express). Previously it was connected to JSON server and everything worked as intended. GET request is working for fine for all database items, I can also POST new items to database via app, however, when I'm trying to access the page to an individual item (e.g. http://localhost:5173/posts/4), I'm getting a 404 not found error.

```
import express from "express";
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import bodyparser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(cors({ origin: "*" }));

app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("Application works!");
});

app.listen(3004, () => {
  console.log("Application started on port 3004!");
});

const mysql = require('mysql2');
const pool = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'root',
    password: '123456',
    database: 'myBlog',
});

pool.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});

app.get('/posts', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  pool.connect(function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      pool.query('SELECT * FROM blog', function (err, result, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.send(result);
          console.log(result);
          });
  });
});


app.post('/posts', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const title = req.body.title
  const content = req.body.content
  const image = req.body.image
  const sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO blog (title, content, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?);'
  pool.query(sqlInsert, [title, content, image], (err, result) => {
  })
})

app.get('/posts/:id', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const id = req.params.id
  const sqlInsert = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id = ?;"
  pool.query(sqlInsert, id, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(result);
    console.log(result);
  })
})
```

And here's the frontend part (no issues when I used JSON server):

```
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useQuery, useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { PostCards } from "../Posts/Posts";
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { AllPosts } from '../Posts/Posts'
import style from '../OnePost/OnePost.module.scss'


const getOnePost = async (id: string) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3004/posts/${id}`)
    return data
}

const OnePost = () => {
    const [updateTitle, setUpdateTitle] = useState('')
    const [updateText, setUpdateText] = useState('')
    const [updateImage, setUpdateImage] = useState('')
    const [showEdit, setShowEdit] = useState(true)

    const onEdit = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setShowEdit(false)
    }

    const { id } = useParams()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const { data, isLoading } = useQuery<PostCards>(['onePost'], () => getOnePost(id!))

    
    if (isLoading) {
        return <h1>Loading...</h1>
    }

    if (!data) {
        navigate('/')

        return null
    }

    const {title, content, image} = data

    const onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setShowEdit(true)
        axios.put(`http://localhost:3004/posts/${id}`, {
          title: updateTitle,
          content: updateText,
          image: updateImage
        }).then(({ data }) => {
            axios.get(`http://localhost:3004/posts/${id}`)
          });
    }


    return (
        <div className={style.container}>
            <img src={image} width='600' height='400'></img>
            <h1 className={style.title}>{title}</h1>
            <p className={style.text}>{content}</p>
            <button className={style.button} onClick={onEdit}>EDIT</button>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className={`editHidden ${!showEdit && 'editActive'}`}>
                <label>
                    Image <br /> <br />
                    <input
                     className={style.field}
                     required
                     defaultValue={image}
                     onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setUpdateImage(e.target.value)}
                     />
                </label>
                <label>
                    Title <br /><br />
                    <input
                    className={style.field}
                    required
                    defaultValue={title}
                    onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setUpdateTitle(e.target.value)}/>
                </label>
                <label>
                    Text <br /><br />
                    <textarea
                    className={style.textarea}
                    required
                    defaultValue={content}
                    onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => setUpdateText(e.target.value)}
                    >
                    </textarea>
                </label>
                <button className={style.button}>UPDATE</button>
            </form>   
        </div>
      
    );
  };
  

  export default OnePost
```

Maybe the issue is the mismatching ports? But in such case why do GET all posts and POST requests work?

Comment: Do you get the same error when you access the URL via the browser?

Comment: Yeah, tried it already - it gives the same error. 5173 is the port I was assigned by react when npm run dev.

3004 was the port I choose for my JSON server.

3306 is the port I used for mysql connected through Docker and VSC Mysql extension.

Comment: Wait, so you tried `http://localhost:3004/posts/4` directly in your browser and still got a 404? Nothing in the code you've shown should result in that response

Comment: I've edited my post and added full frontend code for that particular component.

Yes, I've tried pasting http://localhost:3004/posts/4 in my browser and it's still 404.

Comment: When did you add the `/posts/:id` route? Have you restarted your Express server since doing so?

Comment: So, I've restarted the server just now and now it works - kinda. It opens the page, but doesn't show anything from the database there and the console.log(results) is also not logging out anything. But at least some progress. Thanks a lot!

Comment: FYI you're handling errors incorrectly. See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: Ok, I'll try working on the errors. The strange thing is that, when I click on an individual post it still redirects me to: http://localhost:5173/posts/4, but when I manually change the port to http://localhost:3004/posts/4, it actually directs me to an object with my data.

Comment: Don't you want your client-side routing to use the same `/posts/:id` format? That's why you've got `const { id } = useParams()`. FYI, you should include the `id` in your `useQuery()` query keys. See https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key

Answer (score -1):

Try printing the type of 'req.params.id', it needs to be the same type as your id column. Converting it to int should be:

```
app.get('/posts/:id', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const id = parseInt(req.params.id)
  const sqlInsert = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id = ?;"
  pool.query(sqlInsert, id, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(result);
    console.log(result);
  })
})
```

Comment: This didn't change anything.